# retrieving current node in sequence when looping over this sequence in an xpath predicate

Tags: xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

I need to convert this input xml:

```
<Problems>
    <problem location="engineroom/boiler/nozzle"/>
    <problem location="engineroom/boiler/nozzle/leak"/>
    <problem location="office/printer/paper"/>
    <problem location="office/printer/paper/empty/A4"/>
    <problem location="office/printer/paper/empty/A3"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window/crack"/>
</Problems>
```

to this output xml:

```
<Problems>
    <problem ignore="leak"/>
    <problem ignore="leak"/>
    <problem ignore="empty"/>
    <problem ignore="empty"/>
    <problem ignore="empty"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window/crack"/>
</Problems>
```

My current code involves **hardcoding** the items of interest ('leak', 'empty') and its parent element ('nozzle', 'paper'):

```
    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="problem[contains(@location, 'leak')]
        | problem[ends-with(@location, 'nozzle')][contains(following-sibling::problem[1]/@location, 'nozzle/leak')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display">
            <xsl:with-param name="location" select="'leak'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="problem[contains(@location, 'empty')]
        | problem[ends-with(@location, 'paper')][contains(following-sibling::problem[1]/@location, 'paper/empty')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display">
            <xsl:with-param name="location" select="'empty'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="problem[contains(@location, 'burnt')]
        | problem[ends-with(@location, 'PCB')][contains(following-sibling::problem[1]/@location, 'PCB/burnt')]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display">
            <xsl:with-param name="location" select="'burnt'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="problem" mode="display">
        <xsl:param name="location"/>
        <problem ignore="{$location}"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

What I've tried is the following. But I don't know how to pass the current node in the sequence (e.g. 'leak') to the "display" template.  Also, please let me know if there's a better way than this ugly matching expression. Thanks!

```
    <xsl:variable name="issues">
        <issue name="leak" parent="nozzle"/>
        <issue name="empty" parent="paper"/>
        <issue name="burnt" parent="PCB"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    
    <xsl:template match="problem[true() = (for $i in $issues/issue return if(
        contains(@location,$i/@name)
        or ends-with(@location, $i/parent) and contains(following-sibling::problem[1]/@location,$i/@name)
        ) then true() else false())]">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display">
            <xsl:with-param name="location" select="'???'"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Basically the challenge is to match a string such as "blabla/printer/paper/empty" and "blabla/printer/paper"  or  such as "blabla/printer/ink/empty" and "blabla/printer/ink".  and to be able to pass 'empty' to another template.

Comment: there exists a pure XSLT 2.0 solution, as you are looking for -- no XPAth 3.0 or XSLT 3.0 features such as maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This XSLT 2.0 transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 
 <xsl:key name="kIgnorable" match="problem" use=
   "generate-id(current())
      [$pIgnorable/p[contains(current()/@location, concat('/', @part, '/', issue))]]"/>
 
 <xsl:param name="pIgnorable">
   <p part="nozzle">
      <issue>leak</issue>
   </p>
   <p part="paper">
     <issue>empty</issue>
   </p>
   <p part="PCB">
     <issue>burnt</issue>
   </p>
 </xsl:param>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="problem
  [
   for $part in tokenize(@location, '/')[last()][. = $pIgnorable/p/@part],
       $issue in $pIgnorable/p[@part = $part]/issue
     return
       following-sibling::problem[1]
         [
          contains(@location, concat('/', $part, '/', $issue))
         ]
  ]">
    <xsl:variable name="vPart" select="tokenize(@location, '/')[last()]"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vIssue" select=
    "substring-before(concat(following-sibling::problem[1]
                              /substring-after(@location, 
                                               concat('/', $vPart, '/')), '/'), '/')
    "/>
    <problem ignore="{$vIssue}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="problem[key('kIgnorable', generate-id())]">
     <xsl:variable name="vIgnoreRule" 
       select="$pIgnorable/p[contains(current()/@location, 
                                      concat('/', @part, '/', issue))]"/>
     <problem ignore="{$vIgnoreRule/issue}"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<Problems>
    <problem location="engineroom/boiler/nozzle"/>
    <problem location="engineroom/boiler/nozzle/leak"/>
    <problem location="office/printer/paper"/>
    <problem location="office/printer/paper/empty/A4"/>
    <problem location="office/printer/paper/empty/A3"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window/crack"/>
</Problems>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Problems>
    <problem ignore="leak"/>
    <problem ignore="leak"/>
    <problem ignore="empty"/>
    <problem ignore="empty"/>
    <problem ignore="empty"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window"/>
    <problem location="garage/truck/window/crack"/>
</Problems>
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I have understood the problem but the algorithm presented seems to be implementable in XSLT 3 as

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:map="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions/map"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">
    
  <xsl:param name="relations" as="map(xs:string, xs:string)"
    select="map { 'leak' : 'nozzle', 'empty' : 'paper' }"/>
    
  <xsl:variable name="relation-keys" select="map:keys($relations)"/>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="problem[some $key in $relation-keys satisfies contains(@location, $key)]">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display">
            <xsl:with-param name="location" select="$relation-keys[contains(current()/@location, .)]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="problem[some $key in $relation-keys 
                               satisfies (ends-with(@location, $relations($key)) and contains(following-sibling::problem[1]/@location, $key))]">
       <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="display">
            <xsl:with-param name="location" select="$relation-keys[ends-with(current()/@location, $relations(.)) and contains(current()/following-sibling::problem[1]/@location, .)]"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>      
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="problem" mode="display">
    <xsl:param name="location"/>
    <problem ignore="{$location}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: thanks for your help! I'm still trying to understand how map works, though. It's new to me. Currently getting errors due to duplicate key. But is maps the applicable in the following case? I need a one-to-many relationship. Sorry, I didn't specify this. The list of issues has e.g. 'leak' or 'empty' but the source of the issue is not necessarily 'nozzle' or 'paper', it could be a 'leak' coming, say, a faucet and 'empty' being due to the printer lacking ink instead of paper.   Basically the challenge is to match any string that contains 'leak' or any parent of 'leak'.